# Firebase - secure the database from being deleted entirely

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Doing `CRUD` in `firebase` is pretty easy and neat IMO. But I am confuse on how to protect the whole database.

So I have this `database rules` :

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null",
    }
}
```

Let's say I have a bunch of data on my database. If the user is not yet `authenticated` this code `firebase.database().ref('/').set(null)` is replying a `permission_denied` error which is normal.

But the problem is once a certain user logs in and gets authenticated, this code `firebase.database().ref('/').set(null)` will delete the entire database.

How do I secure this kind of setup? Also when I tried this code `firebase.database().ref('/').set(null)` on the javascript web console it still deletes the data.

Comment: Firebase's security rules allow fine-grained control over who can perform what operation on specific data. See the docs for a good introduction: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen on this sample rules (link below), how does the model should look like exactly? 

 https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-variable

Comment: That has a `/users` with under there a node for each user.

Comment: So are they like `users{ uid1:{name:foo}, uid2:{name:bar}, uid3:{name:baz} }` **or** `users{ user:{user_id:uid1,name:foo}, user:{user_id:uid2,name:foo}, user:{user_id:uid3,name:foo} }`? 

@FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: The first. Try it in the Firebase Console. Create a data structure, write rules, test, and repeat.